# dyn.load error linking a package with Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, ubuntu, rcpp

I've made an R package with Rcpp, to use the methods of a library I programmed in c++.

I've R running on the last version:

```
R version 3.2.5 (2016-04-14)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
```

I'm executing the following instruction to install my package:

```
> install.packages("mypackage", repos = NULL)
```

The package compiles well, I have the .o files of my source code, but in the linking phase I got the error:

```
* installing *source* package ‘rbdd’ ...
** libs
make: No se hace nada para 'all'.
installing to /home/sergio/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/mypackage/libs
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
Warning: /home/sergio/R/mypackage/man/mypackage-package.Rd:27: All text must be in a section
Warning: /home/sergio/R/mypackage/man/mypackage-package.Rd:28: All text must be in a section
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
unable to load shared object '/home/sergio/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/mypackage/libs/mypackage.so':
/home/sergio/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/mypackage/libs/mypackage.so: undefined symbol: _ZN4cudd12defaultErrorENSt3__112basic_stringIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEENS0_9allocatorIcEEEE
Error: loading failed
Ejecución interrumpida
ERROR: loading failed
```

mypackge.so is created in the `src` folder of my package.

I've got a Makevars file (in `src`, too) with the following content:

```
PKG_CPPFLAGS=-I./buddy-2.5/src -I./cudd-3.0.0/cudd -I./cudd-3.0.0/mtr -I./cudd-3.0.0/cplusplus -I./cudd-3.0.0/dddmp -I./cudd-3.0.0/util -I./cudd-3.0.0 -isystem /usr/include/c++/v1 -std=c++11
PKG_LIBS=-lc++ -L/lib
```

and my NAMESPACE file has the lines:

```
useDynLib(mypackage)
exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")
importFrom(Rcpp, evalCpp)
```

Someone knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: Make sure you have `LinkingTo: Rcpp` in `DESCRIPTION` and that you import at least one object from Rcpp in your `NAMESPACE` to ensure Rcpp gets loaded.

Comment: @Jeroen Yes, I have the `LinkingTo: Rcpp` line, and I load Rcpp, I've added the content of my `NAMESPACE` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I am consumming external libs, and I must compile it and execute `ldconfig` before compile my R library.

Answer (score 2):

I am a little concerned about

```
PKG_LIBS=-lc++ -L/lib
```

Did you really mean `/lib`? If it is your library, a more common place would be `/usr/local/lib` which is also search by default.

But, and that is a BIG but, you also need to understand what you need to do for `ldconfig` for the proper setup of `libfoo.so`, `libfoo.so.$MAJOR` and so on. I taught myself that many moons ago from a Linux HOWTO.

If and when that is setup right, you can link it to R via Rcpp. Otherwise maybe stick with system libraries, or package-local static libraries.  That approach will also make your package more portable.

Comment: Thank you!! I am sure that is my problem, I am totally newbie on Ubuntu and I am learning with these mistakes.

Looking for information on how to set up my library I read something about creating symbolic links, but I don't know the destination directory of this operation, or if I need to modify configuration files... And after that I will have my .so file with the MAJOR number?

Can you give me a clue to solve it? I am a bit lost and you look like an expert on these issues.

Comment: This is more involved than I could possible explain here.  Look for tutorials on creating dynamic libraries.